# using powershell to check active IP's or MAC's connected to router

Tags: powershell, scripting, ip-address, router, mac-address

I want to run a Powershell script that talks to the router/AP and figures out what IP (I have Reserved IPS) or MAC address is currently connected to the Router/AP. The script would output what is connected so that I could see "who's home".

At first I used IE though powershell logging into the router and trying to capture data of the wifi client page but I don't think that is the way to go. Is there another way to do this? A way to scan the network without worrying about logging into the router?

Comment: Entirely depends on the router or AP in question. If it has an API you can query, that might be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

If you have DNS resolution on the names of your PCs, you can try this out.

```
$Computer = "value or foreach loop of values" 
$IPAddress = ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($Computer).AddressList[0]).IpAddressToString
$IPMAC = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer 
$MACAddress = ($IPMAC | where { $_.IpAddress -eq $IPAddress}).MACAddress
```

I have tested this with a couple individual names and a foreach loop getting the names from a txt or csv file, and I tested using

```
write-host $IPAddress $MACAddress
```

at the end for a sanity check.

If you want to verify an up/down state of the computer before querying, try using the 'test-connection' powershell command (basically a ping that grabs the results)